# Let X1 be N(0, 1), and let X2 = −X1, if − 1 ≤ X1 ≤ 1, X1, otherwise. Show that X2 also has an N(0,1) distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Given that X1 follows standard normal distribution, N(0,1). And
define X2 = -X1, if -1 ≤ X1 ≤ 1; X1, otherwise. Then I am asked to prove that X2 follows N(0,1) as well.

My idea is to prove P(X1 ≤ x ) = P(X2 ≤ x) for three cases when x < -1 , when -1 ≤ x ≤ 1, when x > 1.
For x < -1 and x > 1 are easy, I started with P(X1 ≤ x) = P(X2 ≤ x) and P(X2 ≥ x) = P(X1 ≥ x) respectively and show that they have the same CDF.

But I am stucked with the case -1 ≤ x ≤ 1,
I was thinking to start with
when -1 ≤ x ≤ 1,
P(|X1|≤|x|) = P(|X2|≤|x|)
and derive from this equation to get P(X1 ≤ x ) = P(X2 ≤ x), but it does not seem to be the correct way.

Could anyone help me with this proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $-1 < x < 1$, and using the standard normal CDF $\Phi(x)$,  you have

- $\mathbb P(X_2 \le x) = \mathbb P(X_2 \le -1)+\mathbb P(-1 < X_2 \le x)$

  - You have already found $\mathbb P(X_2 \le -1)=\mathbb P(X_1 \le -1)=\Phi(-1)$
  - $\mathbb P(-1 < X_2 \le x) = \mathbb P(-1 < -X_1 \le x) = \mathbb P(-x \le X_1 < 1) =  \Phi(1) -\Phi(-x)$
  - $\Phi(1)=1-\Phi(-1)$ and $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$ by symmetry
- so $\mathbb P(X_2 \le x) = \Phi(-1)+(1-\Phi(-1))-(1-\Phi(x)) = \Phi(x)$ as required

Answer (score 0):

$P(X_2 \leq x)=P(-X_1 \leq x, -1 \leq X_1 \leq 1)+P(X_1 \leq x, | X_1| >1)$. Since $X_1$ has symmetric distribution we can change $X_1$ to $-X_1$ in the first term. Hence, $P(X_2 \leq x)=P(X_1 \leq x, -1 \leq X_1 \leq 1)+P(X_1 \leq x, | X_1| >1)=P(X_1 \leq x)$.

[$P(X_1 \in E)=P(-X_1 \in E)$ for any Borel set $E$].